# How to get HTML element with VBA in Excel?

Tags: html, vba, excel

I have an HTML in my Excel:

```
<form name="scform" action="online_range.aspx" autocomplete="off">
<input name="AcctNo" type="hidden" value="3949067512">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="6%"></td>
<td width="18%" align="center" valign="middle"><font color="#ffffff" face="verdana" size="1"><b>Numbers</b>
<td width="18%" align="right" valign="middle"><font color="#000000" face="verdana" size="1">**000,000,000,000.00**</font></td>
<td width="18%" align="right" valign="middle"><font color="#000000" face="verdana" size="1">**100,100,100,100.00**</font>
<td width="5%" align="center" valign="middle"><font color="#000000" face="verdana" size="1">
<!--<a href="javascript:document.scform.submit();" onmouseover="sctest('0479281963'); window.status='Account Details'; return true;">-->
<!-- INSERT BUILDMENU - APSMITH -->
<script>BuildMenu_SCPHP(0,'')</script>
<a onmouseover="showmenu(event,linksetSCPHP[0]); sctest(479281963, 'IM'); window.status='Account Details';" onmouseout="delayhidemenu()" href="javascript:document.scform.submit();">
<!-- END BUILDMENU - APSMITH -->
<img width="21" height="17" src="/images/detail2.gif" border="0"></a>
</font>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></td>
<td width="3%"></td>
</tr></tbody></table></form>
```

I want to get the value from the td which is `000,000,000,000.00` and `100,000,000,000.00` but have no luck.

Here's what i tried:

```
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True

'Navigate to Website
IE.navigate "https://secure1.bpiexpressonline.com/AuthFiles/login.aspx?URL=/direct_signin.htm"

'Loop until page load complete
Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set Doc = IE.document
Doc.getElementById("UserID").Value = Range("E23").Value
Doc.getElementById("Password").Value = Range("E24").Value

Doc.getElementById("login").submit
'Loop until page load complete
Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

'Dim tb As Object, tr As Object, th As Object
Dim tb As Object
Set tb = Doc.getElementsByTagName("AcctNo")

what to do here? i tried getElementsById(td)(1) and so on, but no luck.
```

by using getElementsById(td)(n) there's no error but what the output is wrong, can someone help me or teach me how to parse form type.

thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is very low quality, I edited this but anyway: provide error text, provide more code...

Comment: thanks for your input. i edited the content to show more information.

Comment: Are you sure your "what to do here? i tried getElementsById(td)(1)" is correct? I mean "td"

Comment: Doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText

Comment: it returns "TRUE" value only..

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have difficulties with constructing path to desired element?

1) Add `id` attribute to your table row element, it will be:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3">
<tbody><tr id="row_1">
```

2) Now you can use:

```
Dim row As Object
Set row = Doc.getElementsByTagName("row_1");
```

3) Now you can retrieve get your values like this:

```
row.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).getElementsByTagsName("font")(1).innerText
```

Comment: hi denis. i am not able to add id to tr since the html i posted is an actual html from a site. your understanding is correct but i need to get the value without editing the html.