# VBA Get Name and Date Created of PDF files on a web site

Tags: vba, pdf, web

In VBA (Access): I need to check for the existence of new PDF files on a website, hopefully based on their upload (creation?) date.

Then I need to return the PDF filename and creation date so I can do further processing on that data.

Is there a way to do this in VBA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible, use the object library "InternetExplorer.Application", debug the page and find out the source of the data and check. See what I'm talking about:
[How to get HTML element with VBA in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826631/how-to-get-html-element-with-vba-in-excel)

Comment: Thank! I will check that out.